# Как дождаться выполнения формы, вызванной через метод submit?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Как дождаться выполнения формы, вызванной через метод submit и только после этого выполнить остальной код?
Задача следующая: нужно вызвать форму через js, после чего перейти на другой сайт. Пример кода:

```
document.getElementById('myForm').submit(); 
window.location = "next_page.php"
```

В данном случае форма не успевает выполниться и происходит переход на сайт "next_page.php". Если убрать переход на сайт, то всё отрабатывает как надо. Подскажите, как это исправить?

Comment: что то вроде `target=_blank` попробуй `window.open('http://site.domain', '_blank')`

Comment: Например отправить форму тем же `fetch`, дождаться ответа, после этого выполнить переход...

Answer (score 0):

Это так не работает. Можно конечно что-то придумать с ожидаеним обработки формы. Например, передавать ее через AJAX и т.д. и т.п.

Но вероятней всего в вашем случае все решается проще. В срипте, который делает обработку данной формы после всех операций делаете переадресацию на следующую страницу.

Т.е.

```
//тут обработка формы

//Все успешно обработалось - переходим к следующей странице
header("Location: next_page.php");
exit();
```